# trace of an $H^1$ function is in $H^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary.  Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$.  I would like a reference for the fact that the trace of $u$ on $\partial \Omega$ is in $H^\frac{1}{2}(\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: I guess $H^{\frac 12}(\partial \Omega)$ is defined using a partition of unity $\{\beta_j\}_{1\leq j\leq N}$ subordinated to the open cover $\bigcup_{j=1}^NO_j$ of $\partial(\Omega)$. We can first show that the map $\gamma\colon\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)\to\mathbb R^{n-1}$, $u\mapsto u(x',0)$ can be extended to a linear continuous map $\gamma \colon H^1(\mathbb R^n)\to H^{\frac 12}(\mathbb R^{n-1})$, then use local coordinates. Maybe a good reference is Adam's book, _Sobolev spaces_ but I don't remember if these questions are treated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n case anyone is curious, the answer seems to be at mipa.unimes.fr/preprints/MIPA-Preprint05-2011.pdf, Proposition 4.5.  This is an excellent introduction to fractional-order Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In some books, $H^{1/2}$ is defined to be the trace of $H^{1}$ functions, for example in 
Girault, V.; Raviart, P.-A., Finite Element Methods for Navier-Stokes Equations. Theory and Algorithms

Comment: But it doesn't explain why it's denoted $H^{1/2}$. To see that we need to study Sobolev spaces of type $H^s(\Omega)$, $s\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the answer seems to be at http://mipa.unimes.fr/preprints/MIPA-Preprint05-2011.pdf, Proposition 4.5.

Comment: @user20520 You can answer your own question, for example summing up what is said in the link.

Comment: Unless the answer is completely wrong or a spam, no answer deserves a -1.